# Use numpy vectorize or map to speed up a loop - Python NumPy 3D matrix "get rid of a loop" Python question, Monte Carlo

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, montecarlo

Now I have 1 loop that populates a 3D NumPy matrix.  I'm not exactly the best at understanding a 3D array structure even though I know it's really just a XxYxZ representation of the normal XxY that I'm used to thinking in (2D).  So if you want to know what this is it is a Brownian Bridge (BB) construction used in Monte Carlo simulations for financial problems.  Credit for the original code (derived from the commentary which fixed the original post by author Kenta Oono located here): https://gist.github.com/delta2323/6bb572d9473f3b523e6e.  You don't really need to know anything about the math behind it; it just basically chops up a path of steps (21 in this example), begins at 0, has normally distributed shocks (hence np.random.randn) applied until it reaches the end, which is also 0.  Each path is applied to a simulated price to randomly "shock it" over time, generating a potential path the asset could follow on its way to expiration.  Although these are totally uncorrelated, so I suppose I would pass a V matrix in as well to correlate the paths to be correct, however, let us keep it simple:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import timeit

steps = 21
underlyings = 3
sims = 131072

seed = 0 # fix the seed for replicating results
np.random.seed(seed)

def sample_path_batches(underlyings, steps, sims):
    dt = 1.0 / (steps-1)
    dt_sqrt = np.sqrt(dt)
    B = np.empty((underlyings, steps, sims), dtype=float)
    B[:,0, :] = 0 # set first step to 0
    for n in range(steps - 2):
        t = n * dt
        xi = np.random.randn(underlyings, sims) * dt_sqrt
        B[:, n + 1, :] = B[:, n, :] * (1 - dt / (1 - t)) + xi
        B[:, -1, :] = 0 # set last step to 0
    return B

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
B = sample_path_batches(underlyings, steps, sims)
print('\n' + 'Run time for ', sims, ' simulation steps * underlyings: ', 
np.round((timeit.default_timer() - start_time),3), ' seconds')

pyplot.plot(B[:,:,np.random.randint(0,sims)].T); # plot a random simulation set of paths
pyplot.show()
```

Run time for  131072  simulation steps * underlyings:  2.014  seconds

So anyhow, that's way too slow for my application, although my original version with a 2nd inner loop was around 15 seconds.  So I've seen where people have vectorized NumPy through np.vectorize or used maps to "flatten" a loop, but I can't visualize how to actually do it myself.  I'm looking for an optimal "native Python" implementation that will produce the same numbers.  B is the 3D NumPy array.  You can just copy and paste it and run it online if you want: https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/HEAD?urlpath=lab/tree/demo

Any suggestions are appreciated!!! Even if it is just "restructure the loop like this, then apply np.vectorize" or whatever, I'm pretty good at taking a suggestion and making it work off a simple "new view" into how to visualize the problem.  I would usually just do this type of thing in Cython (nogil / OpenMP / prange) but I'd like to know to "flatten" a loop in general, with normal math libraries built into NumPy or Pandas or whatever works.

Comment: No, neither `np.vectorize` nor `map` would give you significant performance boost against vanilla `for` loop.

Comment: neither `map` or `np.vectorize` speed up your code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I suppose Cython is the way to go then.

Comment: You could try `@numba.vectorize` to minimize rewriting, but you could run into a wall of Numba limitations. Cython requires lots of type annotations to work but that could be a good thing overall.

Comment: Yeah numba @jit has never produced any speedups for the way I write code; call it that I don't understand the format it requires to compile a faster routine, or my routines aren't able to be sped up using that software.  Truly the only thing that has sped up my code in the past, although the effort and time to convert it over is long, is Cython / nogil / inline / OpenMP / prange statements; all using NumPy memory views.  Yes there's a function which can do Mersenne Twister in Cython but it doesn't use any of these optimizations: https://github.com/ananswam/cython_random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution to speed up this code is to **parallelize** it using Numba. You only need to use the decorator `@nb.njit('float64[:,:,::1](int64, int64, int64)', parallel=True)` for the function `sample_path_batches` (where `nb` is the Numba module). Note that `dtype=float` must be replaced with `dtype=np.float64` in the function so that Numba can compile the code correctly. Note that `parallel=True` should automatically parallelize the `np.random.randn` call as well as the basic following operation in the loop. On a 10-core machine this is **7 times faster** (it takes 0.253 second with Numpy and 0.036 with a parallel implementation of Numba). If you do not see any improvement, you could also try to parallelize it manually using `prange`.

Additionally, you can use **`np.float32`** types for significantly faster performance (up to 2 times faster theoretically). However, Numpy do not currently support such types for `np.random.randn`. Instead, `np.random.default_rng().random(size=underlyings*sims, dtype=np.float32).reshape(underlyings, sims)` [should be used](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3155). Unfortunately, it is probably not yet supported by Numba since Numpy add this quite recently...

If you have an Nvidia **GPU**, another solution is to use CUDA to execute the function on the GPU. This should be much faster. Note that Numba have specific optimized functions to generate random `np.float32` values on the GPU using CUDA (see [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.50.0/cuda/random.html#example)).

Comment: Thanks bud, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I've never gotten the format right for numba and thus never seen an actual speedup, but on my PC, this runs in 0.25-0.28s!    It looks like the Numba parallel format follows the NumPy Cython memoryview format.  I tried switching to np.float32 (for all variables inside that could change the that into float64, as well as for B) but the speed is the same with Numba.   So I have enough memory to handle the float64's so this solution works great!

Comment: You're correct BTW that Numba doesn't yet support the new generator objects of NumPy - the correct one is PCG64 for a standard_normal distribution.  Numba just crashes when I add it to generate 32 bit floats, with error messages saying something like "I don't know what to do with this function" loosely translated....

Comment: A guess the speed is not better with float32 types because the random values are generated using float64 and the time to compute random values is probably the bottleneck here. Numba is still quite young and so many advanced functions are not yet (fully) implemented. Still this is a great tool to speed up kernels that would not be straightforward with Numpy. Numba is generally not (much) faster for sequential codes using Numpy functions as Numpy is already quite well optimized. However, it shines with basic loops and on codes that can be parallelized.

Comment: Yes Jérôme Richard it appears that the idea of Numba is to apply it to NumPy specific routines, and most of what I've seen in source is to operate on float64 anyhow.  The new generators for SciPy are not yet supported however, it "appears" they may be by the add-on project https://github.com/numba/numba-scipy but this unfortunately can't support 1.7.1 of Scipy which contains QMC (Sobol) rng generator routines.  That's actually what I'd prefer to use instead of Mersenne twister but for what's available, Numba will do the trick.  Fast loops without Cython.  Always handy :)  Much appreciated.